# Accessing data in a specific column range from csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a `csv` file that I want to load only a specific column range, how would i do that?
Eg: column 5-16

Currently my code loads all of the columns:

```
 this.preload = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.stats = loadTable(
            './data/health/causes-of-death.csv', 'csv', 'header',
            // Callback function to set the value
            // this.loaded to true.
            function (table) {
                self.loaded = true;
            });

    };
this.setup = function () {

 var countries = this.stats.columns;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice` to pick a specific range of columns from the `.columns` array

For example, if you wanted a range from 5 to 16 to be inclusive (includes 5 & 16)

```js
this.setup = function () {
    var countries = this.stats.columns.slice(4, 16);
};
```

Otherwise, exclusive (does not include 5 & 16)

```js
this.setup = function () {
    var countries = this.stats.columns.slice(4, 16);
};
```